# fancyBox: How to get rid of jerky modal window flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancyBox (with a license) on a portfolio site to display an series of images, gallery-style:
[Example](http://designop.us/made/red-front-logo)

When I open one of the images and navigate through the gallery using the mouse or arrow keys, the next image appears about 200 pixels to the right of where it should be before jerking into the correct position. This behavior is not present on the demo site, and I'm not sure why it's doing it in my implementation.

Here's the relevant script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnail-display-link').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
  });
});
```

The script doesn't throw up any errors that in my console, and I don't know where to begin troubleshooting this. Any advice would be gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try strip off the `position: relative;` style from your body tag

Answer (score 2):

The real cause of the problem is that the dimensions of the body element are changed. Since you removed `position: relative;` you are now not able to position relative to it. I recommend using additional wrapping element instead.

Comment: brother John Stephens IMHO uses many unnecessary position relative in his code, which i dont see (yet) other elements (absolute positioned?) that needs to be positioned relative to them, including to this body. so yeah, by quick look, there's no broken layout because of ridden position relative in the body so it's safe